# use absolute or relative path?

Tags: php

in my config.php where i have all constants i set the PATH to a absolute path.

but this means that when i move my application folder i have to change this path.

i wondered if its better to set a relative path, in that way whenever i move my application between production and development folder, i dont have to change it.

how do you guys do when you move between folders?

Comment: how interesting - a question offering two alternatives, which has four answers.     Btw, relative - every time   (hmm, do you count $_SERVER[] as relative or absolute?)

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way I've found is to do the following:

```
define("PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

That gives you the directory of the current file.  If you do this in your settings/bootstrap/init file, you'll have it available to your application, and it will work for any file system.

Comment: My method is similar, except the nesting of the functions. Does it matter, or have I overlooked something?

Comment: Ha ha, nice.  No, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: what does realpath mean? and what happens without it?

Comment: `realpath()` calculates the correct path to a file, resolving any path things like `..\ ` http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: i thought that dirname() also gives you absolut path. but it gives you relative path?

Comment: `dirname()` only returns the directory portion of a file path string.  So if you did `echo dirname("../../x.php");`, you would get `../..` as output.  `realpath()` will convert the relative portions of a file path into the actual hard path.

Answer (score 3):

`__FILE__` is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

```
define('BASE_PATH', dirname(realpath(__FILE__)));
```

This will make your scripts more portable.

Include a file like this

```
include BASE_PATH . 'includes/header.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, absolute paths are bad news.  Even if you don't plan to move, your hosting provider could move you, like DreamHost recently did to me.  I was fine.... 
But there are 14 references to "path" on their wiki:
http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Server_Moves

Comment: This is why the constant declaration was relative to __FILE__, which will always be valid, even if the server moves physically.

Answer (score 1):

I do three things to solve this:

1. The first is to use paths relative to the current file and include things using `dirname(__FILE__).`
2. The second is to use a loader include that all the *pages* load. This file has one responsibility: to find the include directory, usually via a relative call. So long as this relative relationship stays, it doesn't need changing.
3. I also like to support custom settings that belong to the *installation* rather than the *codebase*. This is done by an include mechanism and overrides a few settings that will be specific for the server the code is on.